# Need help finding an obscure and difficult to find seal for my leaking Shower Cubicle

Tags: bathroom, shower, leak, seal

Hopefully someone here will be able to help me in my search for a new seal for my shower cubicle. There appears to be a slot where one should fit but when searching DIY suppliers I haven't been able to find one that looks like it would fit. Everything I find seems to be seals for the bottom of glass shower screens.

I have contacted a number of specialist online retailers who deal in shower seals but none have said they stock a seal that would fit.

Is it possible that it is a custom part for this shower cubicle only? FYI, I live in the UK and this is a shower cubicle fitted to my apartment which was built around 2002.

The picture below shows the inside of my shower door and the groove where I think a seal should go but has probably been removed by a previous tenant.

Any pointers of where to look and what I'm looking for very much appreciated.

[image]

Edit: I looked again and the channel is flowing the water into the side of the door frame it is splashing up and collecting in the groove along the bottom of the door frame as shown int he picture below. It is this that is overflowing and leaking. Is there suppose to be some sealant of some kind in this groove?

[image]

Comment: It could be that is a channel or gutter to catch water draining down the door. The water would flow out the ends where the design is supposed to direct it onto the shower pan.

Comment: Pull back a bit and show/describe where the leak seems to be coming from. As Jim already noted, that's a gutter to catch & redirect water running down, not a holder for a seal.

Comment: It does appear to be leaking from underneath the door, I assumed since it was collecting in there that was the source which was feeding into a groove/channel underneath the door when its closed which is overflowing and spilling out. I will have a closer look when home later see if I can discover an alternative source, Thanks.

Comment: I think getting what are called Channel Seals might be what I'm looking for. No idea which out of the array of ones available but do you think this is the right way to go? [link](https://www.showersealuk.com/shower-door-seal/channel-seals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who encounters a similar situation, I did just find that the channel under the door needed filling with some clear silicone sealant. Once I did that then the leaking stopped.

I have no idea why the sealant was missing, maybe a previous tenant removed it because it got mouldy and looked bad.

Either way problem solved and thanks to Jim and brhans for the pointers that got me to the correct solution.

Hope that helps someone else.